# How to access an element attribute value in C++ plugin?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have this kind of structure inside my world plugin:

```
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <world name='default>

    <plugin name="MyPlugin" filename="libMyPlugin.so">
      <my_box name="box1">
        <pose>0 0 2 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>5 5 4</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
      </my_box>

      <my_box name="box2">
        <pose>10 5 2 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
            <box>
                <size>5 5 4</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
      </my_box>
    </plugin>

  </world>
</sdf>
```

In my world plugin I want to access both <my_box> elements and extract the positions and sizes.

I can get the first <my_box> element by

```
auto my_box_sdf = _sdf->GetElement("my_box");
```

I can check if it has a attribute 'name' by

```
my_box_sdf.GetAttributeSet("name");
```

But I don't know how to get the value of this attribute. I tried all the functions from [here](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/sdformat/api/3.0/classsdf_1_1Element.html) that seemed as if they could return the value, but nothing worked. How do I access the attribute value?

How do I get the other <my_box> element?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20564/how-to-access-an-element-attribute-value-in-c++-plugin?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2018-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I ended up using folowing lines, that do what I need

```
auto box_name = my_box_sdf->GetAttribute("name");
(*box_name).GetAsString();
```

End for access to other <my_box> elements I use:

```
std::vector<std::string>  boxes_name_vec;
while( _sdf->HasElement("my_box") )
{
   auto my_box_sdf = _sdf->GetElement("my_box");
   auto box_name = my_box_sdf->GetAttribute("name");
   boxes_name_vec.push_back((*box_name).GetAsString());
   _sdf->RemoveChild(my_box_sdf);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0